# What differentiates a check from interference?

Tags: rules, ice-hockey, nhl

...more specifically, when a puck carrier dumps it in the zone and chases, this regards when contact is made by the defenseman covering him.

It seems to be a judgement call by the referee whether to allow the check, or to call interference because the defender did not allow the puck dumper to pass him.

Is it a matter of one-hit and it's legal?  Meaning, if the defender lingers and stays with the dumper, then it get called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, if the player has possession of the puck, they are eligible to be legally checked. Officials will give a small amount of leeway if the player has just passed or shot the puck. They will also allow the check if the puck is nearby and the player is trying to play it. Hence, on calls for interference, you will hear the announcers talk about how close or not the puck is.